# Best searching algorithm for Streamin API in JAVA

Tags: java, search

I am using twitter streaming where I am searching for 20,000 keywords like

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length&track=api,software,hardwate,etc
```

Here now I am using sequential search like for loop but its taking very long time to search one twit for 20,000 keyword.

Is any best searching method available in java to search data coming from high traffic http/web.

Comment: a tweet is restricted in size right - so how many words potentially in one tweet? iterate through the words in the tweet and lookup in a set? Surely that can't be that slow?

Comment: @Nim: If I understood the OP correctly, the issue is you have a lot of tweets, and you cannot get them all. You have access to some API that filters the tweets for you according to your "keyword" (search query). Even if it was possible to iterate over all tweets - it was much slower then iterating only the relevant ones. Could be totally misunderstanding though, so I'll be happy to get a reply from the OP rather or not this is indeed the case.

Comment: @KhoyendraPande Did you profile the code? What is the bottle neck? is it the IO of waiting for the http request? If so - parallelizing the requests might be the solution

Comment: @Amit - Not using any stander code just using for loop like -

String keywords={"API","software","hardware"};
for(int i=0;i<keywords.length;i++){
if(streaming.contain(keywords[i])){
break;
}
}

Comment: @KhoyendraPande: So you go over all tweets actually? Also: Does it have to be real-time? Or could you index your data off-line? If the later is true, I believe a classical Information-Retrieveal techique can be used here

Comment: Yeah going to check all twit for all keyword which is taking very-very long time.

Answer (score 0):

If your data doesn't have to be processed in real time, you can use **[information retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval)** (IR) techniques.

Have a back-end server that indexes all the data for you "over night"<sup>1</sup>. It will create an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), and will listen to your app.

**Your app will then query the back-end server** (instead the streaming server), and will "ask" it for the wanted keywords as queries, in the standard IR techniques.

You can use [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) to help you. Lucene is a mature open source information retrieval library, so it can help you with both indexing and querying.

Hope that helps

---

(1) In here "over night" means one of these:

1. If there is a time the app is inactive - it could be done then
2. There are some libraries that support an index to be both queried
   and built in the same time. I cannot recall if lucene is one of
   them.
3. You can use 2 servers, and in each point in time - one will be building index and the other will be available for queries.

Comment: No not using any back-end server, I want to use this in desktop application.